# Upgrading to maven Springboot 5.2.x from Springboot 2.7.x for CVE Vulnerability

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I am a complete Noobie in Springboot framework making simple Rest APIs

We deployed an API and a URL Shortener service for a subsidiary of an Organization who is super keen on Info Sec Aspect

Apparently their InfoSec Team listed a set of Vulnerabilities with CVE ids,
We are currently using Springboot 2.7.7
Many of the CVEs’ that they have added are vulnerabilities (eg. CVE-2022-22965 ) requires
Spring Framework 5.2.22 atleast

https://spring.io/security/cve-2022-22965

**Problem 1)** How to know if Springboot 2.7.7 gets affected by this vulnerability

**Problem 2)** Even if I have to upgrade to 5.x version to remove this vulnerability and transfer the whole existing code and change the version in Eclipse POM.XML I get the following error in POM.XML

```
- Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.Solus_Microservice:reco_API:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:5.2.22 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
- Non-resolvable parent POM for com.Solus_Microservice:reco_API:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:5.2. in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

At this exact location
[image]

And later creating issues in other places like Annotations not getting resolved and stuff

[image]

**Problem 3)** Spring Initializr does not have option for selecting Spring 5.x, just limited to 3.x
Didnt find any tutorial/resource to find how to make a complete maven project with Spring boot of our choice

The Rest API application I am trying to upgrade has a simple Controller-Entity-Repository design that Queries a MySql database

Would be thankful for any help in updating this Vulnerability

Article given below does not give much reference as to where to make the changes
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes

Also read something Conflicting that
`Spring Boot 2.0 builds on and requires Spring Framework 5.` here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#upgrading-to-version-50

Does it mean that I dont need to upgrade in the first place itself

Have pasted my current POM.XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Simple_Microservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>reco_API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>reco_API</name>
    <description>Solus Recommendation API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId> 
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId> 
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                    <version>20210307</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
                <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Your dependencies are a mess, you are mixing incompatible versions. Remove the version from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and for the Spring BOot version use 2.7.14 which will include the most recent Spring version.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're confusing Spring Boot's version with Spring's version. Both of these projects follow a difference release cadence. For example, the current version of Spring is 6.0.x, while Spring Boot is currently at 3.1.x.

This is why your IDE cannot resolve `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:5.2.22`and why you can't select it in Spring Initializr. Spring Boot 5.x simply does not exist.

To find out which version of the Spring framework is used within Spring Boot 2.7.7, you can check [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.7/reference/html/dependency-versions.html)<sup>(1)</sup>. You'll see that this version relies on **Spring 5.3.24**, and thus, should not be impacted by the CVE.

Also be aware that some code analysis tools also sometimes mistakenly identify Spring Boot's version for Spring's version. This can cause false positives to appear in the list of vulnerabilities. That's why it's important to always read the CVE first and double-check whether you're impacted.

---

<sup>(1) Change the Spring Boot version in the URL if you want to check this for other versions as well.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!!
Went and checked the reference docs and found I got nothing to worry about